# WordPress Genesis : Move Header and Navigation Menu Above the Wrap

Tags: css, wordpress

I have to Move the Header and Navigation Menu above wrap, I tried following codes but It moves the header only it does not move the Navigation.

```
/** Reposition header outside main wrap */
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 ) ;

add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_do_header' );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 );

/* Reposition the secondary navigation menu */
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav' );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_do_subnav' );
```

Can anyone guide me or provide me the correct code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
add_action('genesis_before_header', 'genesis_do_subnav');
```

Instead of:

```
add_action('genesis_before','genesis_do_subnav');
```